# Can't use type as type parameter due to no implicit reference conversion

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to build the following structure. The compiler doesn't seem to agree that `ServiceTicketModel` can be implicitly converted to `Model<IEntity>`. Why is this and is there any way to get around it?

```
public abstract class ModelTest<TModel> where TModel : Model<IEntity>, new()

public abstract class Model<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity

public class ServiceTicketModel : Model<ServiceTicket>

public class ServiceTicket : Ticket, IEntity


public class ServiceTicketModelTest : ModelTest<ServiceTicketModel>, IDisposable
```

The error is in the last class, and the message is:

`The type '...ServiceTicketModel' cannot be used as type parameter 'TModel' in the generic type or method 'ModelTest<TModel>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from '...ServiceTicketModel' to '...Model<IEntity>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the compiler is correct... you need to subclass `Model<IEntity>` to satisfy the `where` constraint you added on `TModel`, but you don't - you subclass `Model<ServiceTicket>` where `ServiceTicket : IEntity`. This is not the same.

If this were an interface or delegate definition, you *can sometimes* use variance modifiers (`in`/`out`) to make it happy. But you can't do this with classes.

You may need to use:

```
public abstract class ModelTest<TModel, TEntity>
    where TModel : Model<TEntity>, new()
    where TEntity : IEntity
{...}
public class ServiceTicketModelTest
    : ModelTest<ServiceTicketModel, ServiceTicket>
    , IDisposable
{...}
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful and I will test out your code sample. But can you explain why it's not the same or point me towards documentation that explains this? There is an implicit conversion between ```ServiceTicket``` and ```IEntity``` so why not between ```Model<ServiceTicket>``` and ```Model<IEntity>```?

Comment: @MartBroekkamp it is easiest to explain with an example like `List<T>`; imagine you have a `List<ServiceTicket>`. That means you only expect `ServiceTicket`, right? Now imagine that you can implicitly treat it like `List<IEntity>` because of the implicit conversion. That means you can have `class Foo : IEntity {...}` and add a `Foo` via the implicit conversion. Meaning: allowing `List<ServiceTicket>` to be treated like `List<IEntity>` would allow you to break the invariant that it only takes `ServiceTicket`.